# error "could not load the shared library" api google vms

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-node

I'm doing integration with the google api to manage the vms, the code used:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const compute = google.compute('v1');
    async function listVMs() {
            const authClient = await google.auth.getClient({
              scopes: [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly',
              ],
            });
          
            const projectId = await google.auth.getProjectId();
            const result = await compute.instances.aggregatedList({
              auth: authClient,
              project: projectId,
            });
            const vms = result.data;
            console.log('VMs:', vms);
          }
          listVMs();
```

error I'm getting:

node:internal/crypto/sig:131
const ret = this[kHandle].sign(data, format, type, passphrase, rsaPadding,
^

Error: error:25078067:DSO support routines:win32_load:could not load the shared library
at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:131:29)
at Object.sign (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\jwa\index.js:152:45)
at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:32:24)
at GoogleToken.requestToken (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\gtoken\build\src\index.js:225:31)
at GoogleToken.getTokenAsyncInner (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\gtoken\build\src\index.js:163:21)
at GoogleToken.getTokenAsync (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\gtoken\build\src\index.js:142:55)
at GoogleToken.getToken (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\gtoken\build\src\index.js:94:21)
at JWT.refreshTokenNoCache (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\jwtclient.js:171:36)
at JWT.refreshToken (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:152:24)
at JWT.getRequestMetadataAsync (C:\Users\Mauricio Spagnol\workspace\workBrightCloud\Bright Cloud Web Portal\backend\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:284:28) {
opensslErrorStack: [
'error:0E076071:configuration file routines:module_run:unknown module name',
'error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:module_load_dso:error loading dso',
'error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library'
],
library: 'DSO support routines',
function: 'win32_load',
reason: 'could not load the shared library',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_DSO_COULD_NOT_LOAD_THE_SHARED_LIBRARY'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: I had a similar problem while updating Ubuntu 21 to Ubuntu 22. Seems like some environment variables are no longer pointing at the right place. 
export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null this line will temporaly fix the problem. Coming from this thread. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/issues/351

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the issue is related to the internal nodejs crypto package on the new Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version.

I found the following solution:
get the location of `openssl.cnf` file:
`openssl version -d`

comment out the lines `providers = provider_sectin` in the file `openssl.cnf` and restart application

Answer (score -2):

the solution is to add a certificate to the project to run as https:

- Generate certificate: [How to generate a self-signed SSL certificate using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl;)
- Add server:
  `https.createServer({ key:fs.readFileSync("certificate/key.pem"), cert:fs.readFileSync("certificate/cert.pem") },app).listen(3001);`

Comment: Could you be a more specific, how to do it, please? Some example? Some link? Thanks.